# How to schedule a macro, and to keep trying it until a condition is met?

Tags: vba, automation, scheduled-tasks

Trying to automate sending a daily email based off a csv file that gets reposted every morning, except not at regular intervals. I set my code to start each morning at 09:34:30 and if the file doesn't exist, to try again in 10 seconds.

The main bug I'm facing is if the file doesn't exist, and it the code gets retried, then it will send multiple emails. Below are the relevant parts of code (i edited out the actual url for privacy reasons):

```
Sub Main()

Dim origin As Workbook
Dim dest As Workbook

Dim myURL As String


Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

If WinHttpReq.status = 404 Then 
    Schedule (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")) 
    Exit Sub 'tried this to avoid the bug of repeated emails but it's not working
End If

If WinHttpReq.status = 200 Then

    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "file.csv", 2
    oStream.Close
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("file").Refresh
    Application.Calculate
    Call Mail.email
    Schedule ("09:34:30")
    Exit Sub


End If


End Sub

Sub Schedule(t As String)
    Application.OnTime t, "Main"
End Sub
```

Comment: hi. u are doing a loop. the schedule calls main and main calls schedule.  in main if files doesnt exist , just exit sub with a exit var (no  Schedule (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))  ) and on main create a loop, based on the return var, and call it until file exists (every 10 seconds)

Comment: ok ty i combined your advice and damian's advice below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use:

```
While WinHttpReq.status <> 200

Wend
```

It will loop nonstop until your request status is 200

Comment: Not unless you also put the Send inside the loop - but then you'd be spamming the server...

Comment: Yes that's OK as long as you don't want to do anything else in that excel session   This may be running unattended so that might be fine.

Comment: So what i changed is to get rid of the conditional, replace it with a while status <>200 application.wait, and then initiate the email send after the loop. sorry for the formatting i'm new to stackexchange/coding

Comment: @buttface666 if it worked for you please consider marking this answer as correct.

Comment: i definitely will, unfortunately i have to wait until monday to verify as i'm not in the office during the weekend and would prefer not to have the code running in case something goes wrong